# How to import only a specific database from a .sql file?

Tags: mysql, dump

I have a file `dump.sql` with many databases in it: `mydb1`, `mydb2`, `mydb3`, etc.

How to import only `mydb3` and not the other databases?

Won't:

```
mysql> create database mydb3;
mysql> use mydb3;
mysql> source /path/to/dump.sql;
```

import all databases?

Comment: `source` does not recognize that you want only a subset of the file.

Comment: @RickJames How would you do it easily?

Comment: @ErgestBasha Thanks! Out of curiosity, is `sed` adapter for such kind of tasks? How would you use it here?

Comment: @Basj - `sed` is a simple, general-purpose, command-line editor; it dates back _decades_, long before the term "adapter" was invented.

Comment: @RickJames sorry, I meant "is it well adapt*ed* for this task?" it was a typo :) I don't know what an "adapter" is in this context. My mistake!

Comment: @Basj - If I recall correctly, it can "delete all lines before /.../" and similarly for "after".  Or maybe it is "print all lines between /.../ and /.../".  You would have to look in the file to see where is starts with "use" for the desired db and stops with "DROP" for the next db (or of).  You have the luxury of capturing the output of sed/awk before feeding it to mysql.  (Sorry, I can't even remember which of sed/awk would be better.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [--one-database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_one-database) option or `-o` for short:

```
mysql ... -o mysb3 < /path/to/dump.sql
```

Note that the documentation page in the link above states:

> This option is rudimentary and should be used with care.

However, I think dump files created by mysqldump should be safe enough.

Note: this doesn't run the actual `CREATE DATABASE ...` statement, so you have to do that before you import.

Comment: IHMO This is the most expedient answer without creating another file. If you were doing `mydb1` or `mydb2` like this as well and hit Ctrl-C  when it finishes loading `mydb1` or `mydb2`.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think this is safe, and won't overwrite `mydb1` in the current mysql install if `dump.sql` also contains `mydb1`?

Comment: @Basj Yes, it should be safe as long as the dump was created by `mysqldump` or the dump file is organised so that everything to do with database x is preceded by `USE x;`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sed -n '/^-- Current Database: `mydb1`/,/^-- Current Database: `/p' dump.sql > mydb1.sql
```

Other ways of using sed to get specific tables:

```
sed -n -e '/CREATE TABLE.*`table_name`/,/CREATE TABLE/p' "dump_file" > table_name.sql
```

If you have `.gz` or `.bz2` dumps:

```
gunzip < fulldump.sql.gz | sed -n -e '/DROP TABLE.*`table_name`/,/UNLOCK TABLES/p' | gzip -c > table_name.gz 

sudo bzip2 -d < fulldump.bz2 | sed -n -e '/DROP TABLE.*`table_name`/,/UNLOCK TABLES/p' | bzip2 -z > table_name.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` and `perl` are also good tools for this task.

```
awk '/^-- Current Database: `mydb1`/,/^-- Current Database: `/' dump.sql > mydb1.sql

perl -ne 'print if /^-- Current Database: `mydb1`/../^-- Current Database: `/' dump.sql > mydb1.sql
```

Substitute your schema name for "mydb1" in the above examples.

See:

- https://www.shellhacks.com/sed-awk-print-lines-between-two-patterns/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:

Go back to the original server and dump only mydb3:

```
mysqldump ... mydb3 > db3.sql

mysql ... < db3.sql
```

Plan B:

Edit the dump to extract just the statements needed, then load that subset.  `sed` is one way, most editors is another way; there may be other ways.

Caution:  Be careful to include/exclude the extra commands such as `DROP`, `USE`, etc.

Plan C:

Load the whole dump into a separate instance of MySQL, then do Plan A to copy the db to the ultimate destination.

Comment: Thank you. Plan A is impossible, the original server has been wiped now, and I only have a dump of all databases in a single file. Would you have more details about how to use `sed` for Plan B?

Comment: @Basj - 30 years ago, I could rattle off the details for `sed`, `awk`, `ex`, and maybe some others; I haven't use sed in more than a decade.  Let's hope someone else will jump in.  Suggest you try your favorite text editor (_not_ Word).